# Usage of scapy tcp_reassembly classmethod when using TCPSession?

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

im currently working on a new protocol layer for scapy. unfortunately the tcp_reassembly gives me a headache.

the protocol i dissect uses a bundle_len field that specifies how long a bundle is.
if the packet is exactly as long as the bundle len everything works.
if it is to large i split off one packet and return the rest to the queue (i think)
if the packet is less then the bundle_len im sure i would have to wait for additional packets or prepend the rest of the previous (to long) packet.

i know what the problem is but can't figure out how to use the tcp_reassembly function correctly.

here some example code:

```py
def tcp_reassemble(cls, data, metadata):
        """[called by sniff(session=TCPSession),
        reassembles the tcp stream if packet spans over multiple TCP packets]

        Args:
            data ([Packet]): [a raw packed strippt by the TCP Layer]
            metadata ([dict]): [stores partial streams]

        Returns:
            [Packet]: [reassembled Packet]
        """
        #pylint: disable=unused-argument
        length = struct.unpack("<I", data[24:28])[0]  # get bundle_len, not readable if offset wrong or not a bundle
            if length > 10000:  # desaster containment, not good.
                length = 64
            if len(data) > length:  # got to much
                # return OWN_PROTOCOL bundle up to bundle_len
                pkt = OWN_PROTOCOL(data[:length])
                if hasattr(pkt.payload, "tcp_reassemble"): # not sure if needed or what it does
                    if pkt.payload.tcp_reassemble(data[length:], metadata):
                        return pkt
                else:
                    return pkt
            elif len(data) < length:  # got less, not working
                print(
                    f"### Got LESS actual len: {len(data)} proposed bundle_len: {length} ###")
                return None  # push rest back to queue
            else:
                return OWN_PROTOCOL(data)  # got exactly one bundle in one packet
```